# Why some computer is showing in network

Tags: windows, networking, windows-8

In the network option of windows 8, why some PC's are showing there? My computer name is asus-pc. I am not connected with anyone. Could it be a broadband issue??
[image]

Comment: I gave you [some hints](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576613/why-some-computer-is-showing-in-network#comment60752077_36576613) on your Stack Overflow version of your question, namely: _"try and ping/nslookup the machines to discover their IP addresses. Perhaps you have an open WiFi network, or your ISP has messed things up and you're sharing a subnet with your neighbors"_. Did you try to verify any of that? Also, what do you mean by "broadband issue"?

Comment: **Could it be a broadband issue??** - It is not.  You currently have Network Sharing enabled.  Those other two PCs are connected to your network and also have it enabled.

Comment: @Ramhound yeah but if the OP knew some people named "Sanjoy" and "Sazzad" who are on the same network as them, I'm sure they would've mentioned it.

Comment: @CodeCaster - I know when I lived in 4-bedroom apartment, in my college days, we each had our own "accounts" but the way the apartment was sub-networked we could see each other.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, and that can also happen on the ISP level, where your modem is actually just a bridge to an upstream router which you share with your street or whatever, with no protection (VLANs, ...) whatsoever. The OP should explain somewhat better how this network is layed out and how they connect to the Internet.

Comment: This problem is easy to solve, disable Networking Sharing, but unless they actually share a file with these PCs they can't be access either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are just other computers that exist on your network. If you are at home, these could be family members or roommates. If your on public wifi, these would just be other users on that network.

See [this page on why this occurs](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/view-network-computers-devices#1TC=windows-7). You can use [this page](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-8/turn-sharing-on-or-off) if you don't want other users to view you on the network. You just need to turn internet sharing off.